# Axe the [device]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) currently has 1800+ questions. Its wiki entry consists of:

> Electronic devices: computers, smartphones, tablets, electronic
>   hardware and platforms.

It's general, ambiguous, vague, and not helpful. There are far better, and more specific tags that should be used in its place.

I propose that we burninate the [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) tag. It passes the tests of the [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) question:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **No**
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **No**
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **No**
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **No**

Comment: Shouldn't the title be *"Slice the device"*?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I would suggest *splice* instead

Comment: most should probably be [tag:mobile] or [tag:hid] (or a more specific subtag of those)

Comment: @ivarni Or perhaps *"Turn off the [device]"*? :)

Comment: Detonate Dr. [device]?

Comment: I like how the trend went from the title, to maybe one comment suggesting a better pun, to the whole comment thread solely being about it.

Comment: "You mere device," he gnarled. "You platitude! You Gollux ex machina!"

Comment: Proof of 'tag-by-retyping-title": 50 questions with both [[tag:mobile]] and [[tag:device]], and a further 167 with [[tag:mobile-devices]]!. BURN! BUUUURRRRNNNN!!!!!

Comment: Pretty certain that this tag will come back. Might want to head that eventuality off by making is a synonym for some other useful tag.

Comment: Does `[device]` perhaps indicate something hardware specific?  That would be fairly unambiguous and meaning ful.

Comment: Taking the vice out of [device]. Leaving that tag to its own [devices]. 1800+ questions are held in a (de)vice-like grip.

Comment: Who uses tags anyway?

Comment: No more mr device guy.

Comment: @totymedli "Discard the [device]"?

Comment: Call the cops and make sure they bring de vice squad to get rid of this tag.

Comment: We are all just prisoners here, of our own [device].

Answer (score 21):

Be careful about the diverse meanings for [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device)!

There are 19 cases where [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) is serving to classify a [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) question to focus on mobile applications. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221620/font-size-limit-on-smartphone-but-not-in-table is about css behaviour on a mobile device.

[image: q31221620]

In these cases, we'd probably want to have *some* tag that indicates mobile browser concerns. [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile) smells as bad as [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device), and the tag-wiki is all over the place as well. Other options that I see in a quick survey of [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) questions are listed here, with the number of co-tagged questions in brackets:

- [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile) (2273) - ick
- [media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-queries) (2547)
- [tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablet) (88) - should be burninated along with [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device)!
- [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design) (5506)
- [viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport) (477)

I've gone ahead and retagged the 19 css+device questions to replace [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) with [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design). Same for:

- 13 [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device)([html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) OR [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5))
- 50 with [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) AND [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile), about 50% got [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design), others I just removed [device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device) leaving [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile).